# What's so different/complicated/useful about vectors?

Tags: mathematics, vector, coordinates

Forgive me if this isn't considered a real question, but it is something I am genuinely confused about.

I constantly hear other game developers talk about how using vectors are very useful, but also how everyone is intimidated by vector math and vectors can seem daunting. I have never got around to learning about them.

So, finally I looked [Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) on Wikipedia, and I was surprised. Unless I am somehow mistaken, a vector(for sake of simplicity, say it's 2D), is *just an x and y coordinate.*  If I have misunderstood, please correct me.

So here is my question: doesn't that mean that any representation of two(or three) dimensional coordinates is a vector? If so, then a vectors and coordinates are the same thing. And it's pretty much impossible to create a game *without* using coordinates, so how are vectors confusing or new to someone who has done any amount of game programming?

This is something I could use some clarification on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Vectors are pretty simple up until you start doing rotations in 3D... then you need quaternions and those will blow your mind.

Comment: The notion of vector is really confusing. I have asked in in math, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429363, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384927 but had got no clear response. It is pure frustration. May be you can add to it.

Comment: With all the bad analogies in these answers it's no wonder people get confused.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't let a math major hear you calling Vectors points or coordinates!

A 2D vector has an x and y *component*, not coordinate. Vectors do not define a position, they define a direction and a magnitude.

I can't tell you why people are intimidated by them, likely the same reason people are intimidated by math in general, because everyone says it's hard before they know anything about it!

Vectors and coordinates are not the same thing. They do look similar, but they way they're used is very different.

Coordinates define a position in the world. Vectors define a direction and magnitude. The two of them are often used together. As an example:

A character has a position and a velocity. The position is a coordinate and the velocity is a vector. Adding the velocity to the position will move the character in the direction of the vector at a distance defined by the magnitude of the vector (note that the magnitude of the vector is the speed, so this gives us a direction and a speed).

Or in this example:

[image]

The two characters have positions and the laser shot is a vector. A vector between the two positions is (3,1). That means it travels +3 along the X axis and +1 along the Y axis. Where the magnitude can be found with Sqrt((X*X) + (Y*Y)).

A good overview of vector math can be found on the [Wolfire blog](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/)

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple Thanks for accepting the answer, but I suggest you wait a bit, you might get better answers and people are more willing to answer if there isn't an accepted answer already.

Comment: It's not only Mathematicians who get upset when someone calls a Vector a point or coordinate.  Us physicists will mess you up, too.

Comment: +1 But if I'm nit picking, *velocity* is a vector and speed is the magnitude of that vector.

Comment: @Ergwun Yes that's true, I've edited it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In your example, (1,2), (3,4) and (3,1) denote position. It is nosense to say that all vectors represent angle + magnitude and not  position afterwards. In programming, vectors are objects whose components are fields, which denote either angle or mangitude or position or whatever in rect/polar or whatever coordinates. In math, there is additional restriction on that vectors must be addable and scalable. But, it does not say that the components must be angles and magnitudes rather than coordinates. Afterall, I suspect, you encode the object coordinates by vectors rather than anything else.

Comment: @Val: I wouldn't say it's nonsense. It addresses the question's misconception that vectors are just x- and y-coordinates. Making the answer more formal or accurate by mentioning 'elements of vector space' wouldn't do anyone any good except help explain why people find vector algebra intimidating.

Comment: Do you mean that he says that vector = (x,y) + (length,angle) rather than vector = (length,angle) excludes (x,y)? Well. It reads as if it excludes. Might be he wanted to say that in vector operations chaning x often affects y. But this all depends on operation. I have listened through Gilbert Strang lections and he says that we can translate between coordinates (x,y) and (length,angle) representations of the same vector. Which basis is better depends on operation. You cannot say that vector is (magnitude+angle), especially when you represent them in coordinates (x,y).

Comment: @Val the (3,1) value is a vector with 3 for the x component and 1 for the y component. I agree that it's position is coincidentally close to the position (3,1), but that's not what it's representing. I'm not saying the format of the vectors is (length, angle), as I said in my answer, I'm saying the format is (distance traveled on x axis, distance traveled on y axis). With that information you can derive values for angle and distance, but they are not explicitly written in the format. My answer is for game developers, if you think it's not correct in that aspect, let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: What is the point of differentiating between position and traveled distance? Both position and Δposition are measured in the same units. They are the same type of object. I see your post saying `coordinates define a position in the world. Vectors define a direction and magnitude.`. But in my world, both define a position in space. One is called a rectangular coordinate, another is polar coordinate. I do not understand how you can say that one of them represents a position but another is not if they both represent the same thing and can be converted one to another.

Comment: The vectors are only a position in that they tell you where you would be if you applied them to (0,0). Vectors can modify a position, but don't contain position information in themselves. I understand what you're saying. I think the difference we're talking about is not significant to this question. This is the way vectors are used in game development. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ok, by direction and magnitude you mean the relative distance. But absolute distance (i.e. distance, relative to the origin 0,0) has the same nature and is indistinguishable for any other distance. That is, it also has the magnitude and direction, which "distinguish the vectors from coordinates". What position actually means is the distance w.r.t origin. You can define the position (or distance, if you like) either by Δx,Δy or magnitude/angle. Both define the distance (relative position) in the world. I do not understand what this has to do with vectors. Is Δ = vector and thus the complexity?

Comment: Actually, I do not do game dev. But, I have listened Linear Algebra lectures and their `vectors are positions in space`. Every component is a coordinate and vector is a tuple of coordinates. You apply a matrix operation to the input vector (to the input position) and get another (output) position in response. This is what I see in your gamedev and Mario illustrations. Your vectors are positions (distances with respect to 0,0). I do not understand why you try to persuade that vectors are magnitude+angle. Might be I see that the all difficulty is because you make definitions that makes no sense.

Comment: @Val: any good linear algebra lecture will agree with Byte56: *vectors are not the same as positions in space*.  It makes sense to add “3 miles north and 1 mile east” to “1 mile south”; but it doesn’t make sense to add “the position of the White House” to “the position of the Pentagon”.  Once you fix point of reference as (0,0), you can use vectors to determine points, and vice versa, so in some representations, they look similar; but they’re different.  Abstractly: compare [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) vs. [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

Comment: Your example is incorrect. You say that it is ok to add absolute X plus relative ΔX but it makes no sense to add absolute Y to absolute X. The manipulation is that by position you mean `absolute position` whereas position is always relative to something and adding one mile west does not makes much more sense than the position of Pentagon, especially when Pentagon = 1 mile west w.r.t. the origin. Is all that what you want to say `vector = relative position` when you say that `vector = magnitude+angle`? I do not see any discussion of affine space vs. vector here.

Comment: Thanks @Val, please take further discussion to the chat room.

Answer (score 9):

I think the intimidation factor may arise when you start dealing with more complicated operations such as normalization, dot and cross products, and using multiple coordinate systems with matrices to transform between them.  These are not necessarily easy to understand at first, even if you have a strong geometry and algebra background.

Also, at least in the US, people who have gone through the typical high-school math sequence are accustomed to thinking about geometry in terms of lines, slopes, angles, etc.  They have to unlearn that stuff to some extent, and learn to think about it in terms of vectors and matrices instead.  It's not that the concepts of linear algebra are such a stretch, but that they are a somewhat different set of concepts than the ones used in classical geometry, which people are likely to have learned in school.

---

BTW, the distinction between vectors and points lies in the operations you can perform on them.  Although both are represented (in a particular coordinate system) by a list of components, and therefore look "the same", the operations allowed are not the same.  For instance, you can add two vectors, or multiply a vector by a scalar.  You can't do that with points - or at least, it doesn't make any sense to do so.  But you can subtract two points, and the result is a vector from one point to the other.  You can also add a point to a vector to get a new point.

Points and vectors also behave differently with respect to transformations.  Namely, points are subject to translation, while vectors are not.  Consider the example of an object moving with a position (point) and a velocity (vector); if you translate the object to a different place, you alter its position, but not its velocity.

In fact, furthering this line of reasoning, there are not just vectors; there are other entities like [covectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form) and [bivectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector), which may also "look like" a vector in terms of having a list of components in a coordinate system, but which behave differently in terms of the operations available and the way they react to transformations.  These all belong to a field of math called [Grassmann algebra](http://www.terathon.com/gdc12_lengyel.pdf).  Beyond that, one can be even more general and consider [tensor algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor).  This is advanced stuff though.

Comment: A large part of my confusion was why people thought vectors were so complicated, so this helped. Perhaps I find them simple because I was actually using geometry in programming before I ever took high school geometry.

Comment: You're bringing back memories of Differential Geometry.

Comment: The example of position vs velocity used in a couple of answers breaks down when you have position (point), velocity (vector), and acceleration (vector). If you change the velocity, the acceleration does not change, yet they are both vectors. The distinction between vector and point, while correct, is a distraction - in practice all games store positions as vectors which are implicitly relative to the origin (perhaps indirectly if using a scene graph).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I feel that the distinction between a vector and a position only feels like a distraction when you understand said difference.  Lacking this understanding is precisely the cause of most of the confusion people experience when they first encounter vectors.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton I don't follow your point - if you translate your coordinate system, neither an object's velocity nor acceleration change, but if you rotate the coordinates, then both the velocity and acceleration would get rotated.  So I don't see where anything "breaks down".

Comment: @AlistairBuxton And there's no such thing as "store positions as vectors".  Games store *both* positions *and* vectors as lists of scalar components in a particular coordinate system.  That doesn't make them the same thing.  To make an analogy: ints and floats are both stored as a list of binary bits, yet mean different things and have different operations.

Comment: I do not get the argument of position=point, velocity=vector. The vector is composed of two, vector=(position, velocity). I do not understand what you show by breaking this vector into position+(sub)vector and translating only one component.

Comment: BTW, I can "rotate" a vector so that only one component varies. Suppose you have a vector [p-position, v-velocity]. Suppose its initial value is [p,v] You need to extend it with a 3-rd component, 1. The matrix must keep this component constant, i.e. its last row must be [001]. Since you want to add $a$ to the position, i.e. to the first component and 0 to the second, the frist two rows of the translation matrix must be [10a] and [010]. This matrix translates [p,v,1] into [p+a,v,1]. You see, only position has incremented. So what is the point that you wanted to make?

Comment: @TASagent I disagree. The confusion is caused by pedants spending more time explaining what vectors are not, than what they actually are.

Comment: @NathanReed the analogy breaks down because there are similar coordinate transformations which affect only velocity and not position. This does not imply that velocity is a point and position is a vector, and therefore your analogy does not imply the opposite. And on your second point, can you name a programming language or 3D engine which has different types for Vector3D and Point3D, with different operations available on each?

Comment: So the problem here is that you link position to point and velocity to vector, which is an incorrect mapping. Absolute position and absolute velocity are the same type. It makes no more sense to add the velocity of two objects than it does to add the position of two objects. Subtracting tells you the distance between them or the relative velocity respectively and makes sense.

Comment: @Val You're completely off base.  A vector is not [p-position, v-velocity].  It doesn't have both a point and a velocity inside it.  It's just [x-velocity, y-velocity, z-velocity] (for a velocity vector).  The point is that this is a different type of thing from [x-position, y-position, z-position].

Comment: @AlistairBuxton I certainly have worked with engines that had separate Vector and Point types with different operations.  Just because some particular engine chooses to use the same type for both doesn't mean there is no distinction.  You still get meaningless results if you combine the types inappropriately.  And of course it makes sense to add two velocities; for instance adding the velocity of A relative to B, with the velocity of B relative to C, gives the velocity of A relative to C.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton And there is no coordinate transform that affects velocities but *generically* does not change positions.  If you rotate and your object happens to be at the origin, then sure, its position doesn't change.  But translations *generically* affect all positions but no velocities, and rotations *generically* affect both positions and velocities (and accelerations, etc.)  When you're applying a general affine transform to some [x, y, z] quantity, you need to know whether it's a point or a vector to get the transform right.  They are different types.

Comment: The fact that X and Y are coordinates along different axis does not mean that one of them is a point while another is a vector. The fact that position is not the same as veclocity does not mean that both position and veclocity are vectors. How can your `genericity` change that?

Comment: @NathanReed "it makes sense to add two velocities; for instance adding the velocity of A relative to B, with the velocity of B relative to C, gives the velocity of A relative to C" - you can replace "velocity" with "position" in this sentence and it is still true, hence position and velocity are both the same type.

Answer (score 7):

Vectors really aren't that bad.  There is just a bit of math that people are unfamiliar with.

First and foremost, a Vector does not represent a position in space.  This is conceptually very important.  A vector represents a direction, like 'North', and a magnitude.  On a map with normal Math X-Y coordinates, 'North' would be the vector (0,1) (up on the Y Axis).  This should not be confused with the position (0,1), which is one unit above wherever you put the origin.  *A vector is a direction and a magnitude*.

Displacement (movement) is a vector (like move two units up and one unit Right), Position is not.

Vectors, in and of themselves, are not what people have a problem with.  Usually it's matrices and operations on vectors.

For example, if you multiply a Vector by special matrix called a 'Rotation Matrix', then the vector is rotated by the amount specified by the matrix.  Additionally, some people have issues with Matrix multiplication.  Look it up if you're not familiar with it.

Further, you can 'stack' these matrices (or operations) together.  Like Rotate 90 degrees around the X axis, then Rotate 90 degrees around the Y axis.  If we call the first one Matrix M and the second one matrix N, then the operation would be v*M*N.  However, Matrix multiplication isn't commutative, so that is not the same as v*N*M.

In Graphics programming, you do considerably more complicated operations on vectors and other matrices regularly.  Transformations for FoV and to put your coordinates in screen space, etc.  It's really not that bad, but it can be intimidating for new people.